# Getting FlipClock.js to stop after counting up to a number

Tags: javascript, flipclock

I am having trouble getting FlipClock.js to stop after it reaches a specific count. I have tried using the "`clock.stop();`" call but it doesn't work even after many attempts to set a "stop" number. This is the code I have that works for my counter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clock;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Instantiate a counter
        clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), {
            clockFace: 'Counter',
            minimumDigits: 4,
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
            clock.increment();
        }, 0.1);        
        });             
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas as to how to set my counter to stop at "300"? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT: FlipClock callbacks not being called**

There appears to be a bug in the FlipClock callbacks.

Here's an alternative solution (you appear to have a lot of extra code, not sure why, this is a trimmed down version):

```
    var clock,countup;
    clock = new FlipClock($('h1'), {
        clockFace: 'Counter',
        minimumDigits: 4
    });


    countup = setInterval(function() { 
     if(clock.getTime().time > 300) {
       clock.stop();
       clearInterval(countup);
     }
    },500);
```

Check flipclockjs.com for the documentation on callbacks.

The following is an example:

```
        var clock,countup;

        clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), {
            clockFace: 'Counter',
            minimumDigits: 4,
            callbacks: {
             interval: function() {
               var time = clock.getTime().time;
               if(time > 300) { clearInterval(countup); }
             }
            }
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
         countup = setInterval(function() { clock.increment(); }, 0.1);        
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for that Adam... i tried to use that code but the counter keeps running past 300... I tried to set the time value to "0300" in case the minimumDigits set to "4" might have interfered with the stop value. I also tried using the "setCountdown" function from the flipclock.js file but the same issue...

Comment: Neat - time to start debugging. Enter `console.log`

Comment: File a bug report with the author - it doesn't appear like any of the callbacks are actually getting called like it says in the documentation.

Comment: @Sprout - I've provided an alternative method to accomplish your task. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

You rock Adam... This is what worked in the end...

```
var clock,countup;
        clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), {
            clockFace: 'Counter',
            minimumDigits: 4,
        });

countup = setInterval(function() {
    clock.increment();
        if(clock.getTime().time > 300) {
        clock.stop();
        clearInterval(countup);
        }     
}, 0);
```