# Javascript/jQuery FlipClock destroy/clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I'm trying to use this [FlipClock plugin](http://web.archive.org/web/20191208040027/http://flipclockjs.com/#409).

```js
var clock = $(".clock").FlipClock({
    clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock',
    callbacks:{
    }
});
```

```css
/* Get the bourbon mixin from http://bourbon.io */
/* Reset */
.flip-clock-wrapper * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ccc; }

.flip-clock-wrapper a:hover {
  color: #fff; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  list-style: none; }

.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:before,
.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table; }

.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:after {
  clear: both; }

.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1; }

/* Main */
.flip-clock-wrapper {
  font: normal 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-user-select: none; }

.flip-clock-meridium {
  background: none !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 !important;
  font-size: 36px !important; }

.flip-clock-meridium a { color: #313333; }

.flip-clock-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper:before,
.flip-clock-wrapper:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}
.flip-clock-wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}

/* Skeleton */
.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 90px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 87px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #000;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 87px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li:first-child {
  z-index: 2; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-perspective: 200px;
  -moz-perspective: 200px;
  perspective: 200px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
  cursor: default !important; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 80px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  outline: 1px solid transparent; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div .shadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  top: 0; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  color: #ccc;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 70px; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up div.inn {
  top: 0; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down div.inn {
  bottom: 0; }

/* PLAY */
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before {
  z-index: 3; }

.flip-clock-wrapper .flip {   box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active {
  -webkit-animation: asd 0.01s 0.49s linear both;
  -moz-animation: asd 0.01s 0.49s linear both;
  animation: asd 0.01s 0.49s linear both;
  z-index: 5; }

.flip-clock-divider {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px; }

.flip-clock-divider:first-child {
  width: 0; }

.flip-clock-dot {
  display: block;
  background: #323434;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: 5px; }

.flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5em;
  right: -86px;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: none; }

.flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label {
  right: -88px; }

.flip-clock-divider.seconds .flip-clock-label {
  right: -91px; }

.flip-clock-dot.top {
  top: 30px; }

.flip-clock-dot.bottom {
  bottom: 30px; }

@-webkit-keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

@-moz-keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

@-o-keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

@keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .down {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: turn 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: turn 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  animation: turn 0.5s 0.5s linear both; }

@-webkit-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

@-o-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

@keyframes turn {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .up {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: turn2 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: turn2 0.5s linear both;
  animation: turn2 0.5s linear both; }

@-webkit-keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

@-o-keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

@keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li.flip-clock-active {
  z-index: 3; }

/* SHADOW */
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .up .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(100%, black));
  background: linear, top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%;
  -webkit-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  animation: show 0.5s linear both; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .up .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(100%, black));
  background: linear, top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%;
  -webkit-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  -moz-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both; }

/*DOWN*/
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .down .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, black), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)));
  background: linear, top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  -webkit-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  animation: show 0.5s linear both; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .down .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, black), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)));
  background: linear, top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  -webkit-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  -moz-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  animation: hide 0.5s 0.2s linear both; }

@-webkit-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-moz-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-o-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-webkit-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@-moz-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@-o-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }
```

```html
<div class="clock"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.7/flipclock.min.js" integrity="sha512-Vy4ftjkcjamOFPNSK7Osn8kYhF7XDcLWPiRvSmdimNscisyC8MkhDlAHSt+psegxRzd/q6wUC/VFhQZ6P2hBOw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

I wonder if do We have possible to destroy/clearInterval `var clock;` just using `clearInterval(clock)` ? Tried and no luck.
I already open the manual documentation, but seems I'm not so understand how to destroy that.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on the problem you are having, nor what your question is; in your snippet I see an animated clock that seems to be running fine with no console errors...

Comment: Hi, Now I need to stop the clock by using `clearInterval` or `destroy` something like that.

Comment: Here I found a similar question with an accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038808/getting-flipclock-js-to-stop-after-counting-up-to-a-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation you linked, the [clock instance has [`.stop()` and `reset()` methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20191208040027/http://flipclockjs.com/#stop)...

```js
var clock = $(".clock").FlipClock({
    clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock',
    callbacks:{
    }
});

function stopClock() {
  clock.stop();
}
```

```css
/* Get the bourbon mixin from http://bourbon.io */
/* Reset */
.flip-clock-wrapper * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ccc; }

.flip-clock-wrapper a:hover {
  color: #fff; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  list-style: none; }

.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:before,
.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table; }

.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:after {
  clear: both; }

.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1; }

/* Main */
.flip-clock-wrapper {
  font: normal 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-user-select: none; }

.flip-clock-meridium {
  background: none !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 !important;
  font-size: 36px !important; }

.flip-clock-meridium a { color: #313333; }

.flip-clock-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper:before,
.flip-clock-wrapper:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}
.flip-clock-wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}

/* Skeleton */
.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 90px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 87px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #000;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 87px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li:first-child {
  z-index: 2; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-perspective: 200px;
  -moz-perspective: 200px;
  perspective: 200px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
  cursor: default !important; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 80px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  outline: 1px solid transparent; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div .shadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  top: 0; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  color: #ccc;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 70px; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up div.inn {
  top: 0; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down div.inn {
  bottom: 0; }

/* PLAY */
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before {
  z-index: 3; }

.flip-clock-wrapper .flip {   box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active {
  -webkit-animation: asd 0.01s 0.49s linear both;
  -moz-animation: asd 0.01s 0.49s linear both;
  animation: asd 0.01s 0.49s linear both;
  z-index: 5; }

.flip-clock-divider {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px; }

.flip-clock-divider:first-child {
  width: 0; }

.flip-clock-dot {
  display: block;
  background: #323434;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: 5px; }

.flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5em;
  right: -86px;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: none; }

.flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label {
  right: -88px; }

.flip-clock-divider.seconds .flip-clock-label {
  right: -91px; }

.flip-clock-dot.top {
  top: 30px; }

.flip-clock-dot.bottom {
  bottom: 30px; }

@-webkit-keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

@-moz-keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

@-o-keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

@keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .down {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: turn 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: turn 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  animation: turn 0.5s 0.5s linear both; }

@-webkit-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

@-o-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

@keyframes turn {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .up {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: turn2 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: turn2 0.5s linear both;
  animation: turn2 0.5s linear both; }

@-webkit-keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

@-o-keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

@keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li.flip-clock-active {
  z-index: 3; }

/* SHADOW */
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .up .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(100%, black));
  background: linear, top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%;
  -webkit-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  animation: show 0.5s linear both; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .up .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(100%, black));
  background: linear, top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%;
  -webkit-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  -moz-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both; }

/*DOWN*/
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .down .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, black), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)));
  background: linear, top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  -webkit-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  animation: show 0.5s linear both; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .down .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, black), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)));
  background: linear, top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  -webkit-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  -moz-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  animation: hide 0.5s 0.2s linear both; }

@-webkit-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-moz-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-o-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-webkit-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@-moz-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@-o-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }
```

```html
<div class="clock"></div>

<button onclick="stopClock()">stop</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.7/flipclock.min.js" integrity="sha512-Vy4ftjkcjamOFPNSK7Osn8kYhF7XDcLWPiRvSmdimNscisyC8MkhDlAHSt+psegxRzd/q6wUC/VFhQZ6P2hBOw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: You safe my day!

Answer (score 0):

The clearInterval() method clears a timer set with the setInterval() method.

The ID value returned by setInterval() is used as the parameter for the clearInterval() method.

Note: To be able to use the clearInterval() method, you must use a variable when creating the **interval** method:

Here clock variable is not a timer set with setInterval so you can't use clearInterval.

Events callback should help you to do your thing .